# Steam API: accessing DOTA2 ranked matches

Tags: steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I'm trying to use the Steam HTTP-based API to get information about ongoing and recently completed Ranked Matchmaking DOTA2 games. Specifically, I'm using the command

```
https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/V001/?format=json&key=<my_key>
```

I noticed that in the hundreds of games that I've looked at using this request, there is not a single ranked matchmaking game (lobby_type=7). Most games are lobby_type 4 (co-op versus AI), type 8 (solo mid), or type 0 (unknown). Why can't I see the ranked matchmaking games?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ranked games the Web API seems to be [currently broken](https://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=285135).

As far as I know there is no official statement yet.